$f(z)= \frac{1}{z^2-z}$ has primitive on $\mathbb{C}-[0,1]$
We have $f(z)= \frac{1}{z^2-z}= \frac{1}{z(z-1)}$; so $f$ has got $2$ poles at  $z=0,1$ and if we consider $\gamma$ to be a simple loop in $\mathbb{C}-[0,1]$, we should have that $ind(0,\gamma)=0 \iff ind(1,\gamma)=0$ because if not so, we'd obtain that $[0,1]$ was not connected; but then we have:
$$\int_{\gamma}f dz=2\pi i (res(0,f)+res(1,f))=2 \pi i (-1+1)=0$$
And in the other case, we have by Cauchy's theorem, that $\int_{\gamma} f dz=0$ as $\gamma$ is null-homotopic in the domain of $f$
From this, it follows that $f$ has got a primitive in $\mathbb{C}- [0,1]$; is this argument correct?
How could I better justify that $P \cap int(\gamma)=\{0,1\} \lor P \cap int(\gamma)=\emptyset$; where $P$ is the set of poles of $f$?

$- log (\frac z {z-1})$ is a primitive of $f(z)$ in $\mathbb{C}-[0,1]$ if $log$ is an analytic branch of logarithm in $\mathbb C \setminus [0,\infty)$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972168
